# Ubuntu One refuses my 11 character login

Tags: ubuntu-one

Okay, I go to register in Ubuntu One. Everything looks good. I put in an 11 character password `B*********1`, with one major character and one number, but I keep on getting the error message that I have to have at least 8 characters, one capital or major letter and one number. Now if this isn't what was asked for, as I marked above, what is wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but you could try to change your password trough the web interface to a shorter one. If it works, at least you know where the problem is.

Comment: It seems that I don't have my cookies set up properly and Ubuntu doesn't like it, but gives me no suggestion, really, as to how to correct it - I use FF 6.0.2, in the event that anyone has any ideas. 

Thanks for your Helpful input Darent.

Answer (score 0):

To reset ***all*** pf your Firefox Settings:

1. Open your Home Folder.
2. Press `Ctrl+H`
3. Delete the `.mozilla` folder.

You should now be able to register on the [Ubuntu One Site](http://one.ubuntu.com/).